# One headlight stuck in high beam mode + other electrical gremlins after head unit install

Tags: electrical, ford, brakes, headlight, mustang

This is a 2002 Ford Mustang base model.

One of my headlights is stuck on high beams the other is on low. When I turn my high beams on both are high.

Not sure if this has anything to do with it but when I press down on my brake pedal my power dims a little.

Also, my ABS light is on and my traction control off button is on.

It’s never done these things before I put my new stereo head unit in.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!